# Order of setTimeout calls

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I am using `setTimeout` to visualise a reinforcement learning algorithm and am curious as to its behaviour.

The following code shows setTimeout used in a while oop.  Each iteration of a loop should use a version of `state`, which has been modified by the previous iteration.  Is there any possibility that  the second call to setTimeout will occur before the first, and the value of state will not be updated correctly?  I ask partly because I think I have actually noticed some strange behaviour, where when the delay period is too small, the console logs of calls to doLearningInnerLoop are out of order (i.e time will = 1 4 3 2 5 6 ..etc).

```
var doLearningInnerLoop = function(time, observedData, stateHolder, domain, sampleAction, selectModel, numSamples, depth, discount, stateQueries) {
    console.log("new Round, time = " + time);
    var state = stateHolder.state;
    var currentModel = selectModel(observedData, 10, stateQueries);
    var bestAction = sparseSampleMcmc(depth, numSamples, discount, currentModel, state, sampleAction, stateQueries);
    var newStateReward = domain.executeAction(bestAction, stateQueries);
    observedData.push(bestAction, newStateReward[1], newStateReward[0]);
    stateHolder.state = newStateReward[0];
}

var doLearningLoops = function(time, observedData, state, domain, sampleAction, selectModel, numSamples, depth, discount, stateQueries) {
    stateHolder = {};
    stateHolder.state = state;
    while(stateQueries['canContinue']['codeAsFunction'](time, stateHolder.state) === true) {
        setTimeout(doLearningInnerLoop, 1000, time, observedData, stateHolder, domain, sampleAction, selectModel, numSamples, depth, discount, stateQueries);
        time += 1;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry, timers in JS are always executed in order.

Comment: I don't know of this behaviour, but note that there is a [minimum delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting). Perhaps you can get strange results if you set a delay smaller than the minimum delay.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a similar issue of setTimeout calls not happening in the expected order.

see: [Are equal timeouts executed in order in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776239/are-equal-timeouts-executed-in-order-in-javascript)

The answer above is that Firefox appears to do it properly (based upon the source) but someone else has also some up against the issue (maybe they were on a different browser).