# Order of $timeout callback execution when you have multiple

Tags: angularjs, timeout

If I have 2 $timeouts one after another in a function, can I know for sure that the $timeout1's callback will be called before $timeout2's callback?

```
function tempFunction() {
    $timeout(function() {
        //timeout 1s callback code
    });

    //some other procesing

    $timeout(function() {
        //timeout 2s callback code
    });
}
```

Does timeout1s callback get called before timeout2s callback? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout` is an angular's wrapper for `setTimeout`. So your question can be related to this: [Execution order of multiple setTimeout() functions with same interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771558/execution-order-of-multiple-settimeout-functions-with-same-interval).

From the spec there it looks like the order should be guaranteed, but it can depend on environment. Even for different (but close) delay values there are some examples of random results.

For me, to be sure (and browser independent) the best way is to chain those calls (already described in another answer) like for any other async stuff you want to assure order of.

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout` returns a promise. You can chain them.

```
var p1 = $timeout(fn1);

var p2 = p1.then(function(){
             return $timeout(fn2);
         };
```

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg. While helpful, that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://tech.endeepak.com/blog/2014/05/03/waiting-for-angularjs-digest-cycle/) person has noted, the $timeout ensures that the callback is called at the beginning of the next digest cycle. Now this is all this function does when the callback is the only argument passed. Using $timeout with the additional int argument ( $timeout(function() {...}, integer) ) will both wait for the next digest cycle and the elapsed specified milliseconds before executing the callback.

In addition to this $timeout takes a third optional argument which is a boolean that allows you to specify if $apply() is called. This defaults to true.

Because of this cb1 will be executed before cb2 since it will call $apply() first, but both will wait for the beginning of the next digest cycle.