# jquery each() with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object filled with various elements that I wish to iterate through using `each()` and then perform an action on the element whose turn it is. So:

```
var arts = $("#press-sqs > article");
shuffle(arts);

$(arts).each(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
    // in here perform an action on the current element in 'arts'
    }, 2000);   
});
```

( `shuffle()` is a basic shuffle function )

What I can't figure out is how to access the current element as a selector and perform an action on it. `$(this)` is `$(window)`.

Finally I would then need the function to start the iteration again once it reaches the end of `art` and keep on looping ad infinitum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using `setInterval`, you'd get identical results swapping the order:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(arts).each(function(){
         doSomethingWith(this);
    });   
}, 2000);
```

I don't think you want what you think you do here. I reckon you want:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    var art = arts[i++];
    doSomethingWith(art)
    if(i >= arts.length) i = 0;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: clever chap, you figured out what I meant. I don't think I made it especially clear but this is the exact result. Thanks

Comment: I disagree that results are "identical" when swapping the order (elements would be processed in a different order), but I bet you're right about the "real" intention. (**edit:** and turns out, you were!)

Comment: Any chance you could explain what's happening in that second sample?

Comment: @artparks: Which bit are you having trouble with? `i` is just an index into the array, which gets incremented every 2 seconds.

Comment: @WillPalmer: Is there a defined order for the original case? I guess you could argue that the difference is whether the order is defined.

Comment: sorry, yes, that was indeed what I meant. According to [are-equal-timeouts-executed-in-order-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776239/are-equal-timeouts-executed-in-order-in-javascript), the order is implementation-dependent (though all major browsers appear to have the same implementation at the moment)

Comment: I think I get it - I assume `setInterval` is actually doing the iteration itself? Otherwise I can't understand how it's looping through the object. `i` just resets when it gets bigger than `arts`, hence it looping infinitely, I get that bit!

Comment: @artparks: Yes, `setInterval` does the iteration. `setInterval(f, n)` calls `f` every `n` milliseconds, forever.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `.each(...)` method passes the "current" element (and its index) into the callback. `this` is just a convenience for when you don't need to do anything too complicated.

```
$(arts).each(function(i, current){
    setInterval(function() {
    // in here perform an action on the current element in 'arts'
    }, 2000);   
});
```

Above, the current element is available within the setInterval callback as `current`, for example. Note that this element is passed in its "raw" form, as `this` is, so if you want to call jQuery methods on it, you'll need to wrap it in the same way, ie: `$(current)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use that.

```
$(arts).each(function(){
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function() {
    // in here perform an action on the current element in 'arts'
         doSomethingWith(that)
    }, 2000);   
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work... `$(that).children(".sq-logo").hide();` for example hides all the children with that class, not just the children of the element currently being iterated

Comment: @artparks: That's because you iterate your elements immediately!

Comment: Most likely what you really want is a setInterval around the each, and a setTimeout inside the each with a delay based on index.