# using setInterval and jquery to switch background image of a div

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have this code that is supposed to rotate some background images of a div.

```
<style>

.slider{
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('img/placeholder.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}    
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = ['url("img/placeholder.png")',
            'url("img/img1.jpg")',
            'url("img/img2.jpg")',
            'url("img/img3.jpg")',
            'url("img/img4.jpg")'];

    $.each(images, function(i, val){
      setInterval(function(){
          $('.slider').css({backgroundImage: val});
      }, 5000);
    });

});
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row slider"></div>

</div>
```

The problem is that it will only show the last image that is into the array. Is it possible to fix this, I'm not too experienced using javascript/jquery loops so I suppose that the problem is with the `$.each()` loop code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var images = [
    'url("https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2017/04/24/6-165890-cat-1493062781.jpg")',
    'url("https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/3asSf7LmvyrY5m0-ggxJjrnd_DI=/800x600/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.smithsonianmag.com/filer/58/04/5804c840-3073-4ecf-a1d2-37808419fe93/gdahh5-wr.jpg")',
    'url("https://static.toiimg.com/img/60828043/Master.jpg")',
    'url("https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2015/cat.jpg")'
  ];

  var i = images.length;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (i == images.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    $('#slider').css("background-image", images[i]);
    i++;
  }, 1000);


});
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

The first second there are no images, because there are no default background image. You could simply add a default background by adding this line before the `setInterval` :

```
$('#slider').css("background-image", images[images.length-1])
```

This way you would always start with the last element in the array and then go back to the first one and continue normally. You could change the logic, this is just a bonus :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. The code is for a custom carousel based on bootstrap 4 and the number of the images will change from project to project.

Comment: @user9741470 I edited the code to work for any number of images.

Comment: thank you. I've tested the solution you have suggested and it's perfect. Is it possible to achieve this also with the `$.each()` loop?

Comment: @user9741470 [maybe but I don't think it is..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588617/jquery-each-with-setinterval) I do find my solution enough for your simple problem tho. It's up to you.

Comment: ok, just the last thing. If i add a `fadeIn()` effect to make the transition more soft and smoother, it will work?

Comment: @user9741470 I'll let you [test and try to figure out](https://jsfiddle.net/xtq75vdw/), feel free to post another question if you're not able to :-)

Comment: I've added a `transition: all 300ms ease` to the css and `fadeIn('slow')` to the code, and it's seems to work perfect.