# Javascript setTimeout parameter reversing from loop

Tags: javascript

This loop is in a function and it counts down from 10, however if I alert the parameter passed using `i` in the `setV` function it actually counts up!

```
for (var i=10;i>0;i--){
setTimeout('setV('+i+',"Out")',100);
}


function setV(c,t){
alert(c);
}
```

Comment: If you're doing `alert(i)`, it doesn't count up. It should give you `0` for every alert, because that's the value of `i` when the setTimeout callbacks run.

Comment: @user1689607 not really. The value is captured by string concatenation.

Comment: All of those fire right after each other, and in reverse order (10,9,8,7,6...). What's the problem?

Comment: @JanDvorak: OP is talking about alerting `i`. Unless I'm misunderstanding the point.

Comment: @user1689607 he alerts the first argument, which gets its value from `i`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Read the first sentence starting with *"however..."*. I'm pretty sure OP is showing the working code that counts down, and is asking about the "however" part. But maybe I'm wrong. Either way, it shouldn't count "up".

Comment: @user1689607 i is evaluated before it is concatenated, so it won't always alert 0. You're right though, it shouldn't count up, it should count down, which it does.

Comment: @Asad: I just had this conversation. Please read the above comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the setV are programmed to execute at the same time (100ms after the instaneous loop execution), the order isn't determined (see [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers)).

You probably wanted

```
for (var i=10;i>0;i--){
   setTimeout('setV('+i+',"Out")',100*(11-i));
}
```

Comment: so I can't use a for loop to trigger the animation frames?

Comment: I edited : to have the same order you should use 100*(11-i) (or (10-i) to have it start immediately.

Comment: @user1209203 The reason it counts "the wrong way" is because a callback set for 100ms fires before one set for 200ms and so forth

Comment: The order isn't determined? Even though the duration is the same, the order will be maintained... unless you can show a working demo that suggests otherwise,.

Comment: @user1689607 The margin of error in javascript timers of 2 or 3 ms could be the time it takes to execute the next iteration, in which case the order could get scrambled

Comment: @Asad: I'd guess that the margin of error is even greater than that in some implementations. I'd still like to see a demo in an implementation that doesn't preserve the original scheduled order.

Comment: @user1689607 Here's [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers). Do you see a guarantee regarding order of same time programmed timers related to queuing order ?

Comment: @dystroy: Not explicitly, but by that reasoning, timers scheduled with an explicitly different duration could happen in random order simply by virtue of the inaccuracy of JS timers. I'd like to see at least one implementation that doesn't honor the call order when the duration is identical.

Comment: I never spoke of inaccuracy. When you write a queue, it's sometimes more efficient to dequeue in LIFO order. And as the desired behavior for same time timers isn't defined, there is no reason to presume the insertion order would prevail.

Comment: @user1689607 Here's an example with the error exaggerated to 10ms. http://jsfiddle.net/kB2jr/

Comment: @Asad That example is flawed, because the timeout values are not identical.

Comment: @Asad: ^^ What RobW said before my wireless connection dropped. :) I'm not saying that the duration is ignored. I'm saying that when identical *(or even varied within the timers margin of error)*, the original call order is maintained.

Comment: @RobW That's interesting but I don't see where it says that timers are queued using an event loop.

Comment: @RobW This should prove my point : http://jsfiddle.net/HfWwe/ (at least on Chromium it doesn't execute in order).

Comment: @dystroy Ah, [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776239/are-equal-timeouts-executed-in-order-in-javascript).

Comment: @RobW: I think that's a bug specific to using `alert()` in Chrome. Here's a [different test](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu8Zs/) that increases the loop to 1000, caches `i` to an Array, then compares the order after it's finished. The order is preserved for all 1000 items in Chrome.

Comment: @dystroy: The event loop description can be seen when you click the [Queue](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) link at step 10.

Comment: @dystroy: Yes, I saw that, but I responded that I believe this is a bug specific to `alert()`. I can't get a varied order when not using `alert()`. The test I posted shows the order being preserved perfectly. And why is it a missing link? They directly link to that document from the timers doc. Am I misunderstanding what you meant?

Comment: @user1689607 OK, I got your comment : I see the link. But I understand that the callbacks are added to the ordered queue when they're eligible, not when you call setTimeout. What matters is how the "list of active timers" is dequeued

Comment: @dystroy: Certainly we can agree that the concatenation takes places synchronously in the loop, and the calls to `setTimeout` also happen synchronously. So the only remaining question is the order that those timers are executed. Because the strings are definitely concatenated and passed in order, if the timers happened out of order, the concatenated `i` would be added to the `cache` in a non-sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are describing the behavior with:

```
setTimeout('setV('+i+',"Out")',i*100);
```

the reason it counts up is because a callback set for 1s will execute earlier than one set for 2s, which will execute earlier than one set for 3s...

Answer (score 0):

When all of the timeouts are set to run at the same time, there is no promise what order they will run this.

This is a much better way to write that loop:

```
  function initThis() {
    var idx = 0;
    function doOneIteration() {
      window.alert(idx);
      idx++;
      if (idx <= 10) {
        window.setTimeout(doOneIteration);
      }
    }
    doOneIteration(); // Start loop
  }  


  initThis();  // This makes it all happen
```