# Settimeout and ClearTimeout

Tags: javascript, set, cleartimeout

i need to restart a `setTimeout` after stopping it with a `clearTimeout`
the code is like:

```
function start(){timeout = setTimeout(function(){...}, 1000}
function increment(){interval();}
function stop(){clearTimeout(timeout)}
```

better explained:
`function start()` is a timeout of 1000ms for another function that recall `start()`.
`function increment()` just add +1 to a value every 1000s but it doesn't matter with the problem.
the last `function stop()` stops the `setTimeout` in the `function start()`. 
i need to stop the `setTimeout` in `start()` for just 1000ms and then let it continue working.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i tried with another setTimeout but with this the +1 every second in increment() becomes not regular (it jumps 2-3 points 1 sec, then 4 - 5 points...)

Comment: `stop(); start();`?

Comment: How to stop setTimeout for 1000ms and then let it works normally

Comment: I dunno how they work... stop() start()...?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. Can you perhaps put it in a snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Just call `start` after a delay: `function stop() {clearTimeout(timeout); setTimeout(start, 1000);}`.

Comment: You can't rely on [setTimeouts to run sequentially](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998338/542251) or for that matter for them to run exactly within the period defined. The event will be "fuzzy" depending on what else is in the event queue

Comment: function stop() {clearTimeout(timeout); timer = setTimeout(start, 1000);}
kinda working

Comment: If you want something to run sequentially in JavaScirpt you should use call backs

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/th4p68h3/ (id and classes are in italian... sorry for that)
here it is the "game" i'm doing....
what i need is add a period of time (1s) in which the footballer stop doing points....

Comment: kinda works because the 1s delay stays forever whene i need it for 1 time...

Comment: @Maker You never said that in your question. Then just create a flag, that the first option has already been used ...

Comment: doing so you just add 1000ms to the first setTimeout... so is not what i asked...

Answer (score 0):

ok.... i "avoid" the problem....
i need to stop the setTimeout for 1000ms and then let it works normally...
i tried so... instead of pausing the setTimeout I put another time var.

```
 var time = 1000;
    var timecache = 1000;
    fatica = 3000;
    sudore = 3000;
    function interval() { timeout = setTimeout(increment, time);} //here setTimeout uses var time//
    function increment(){console.log(time);point += 1;document.getElementById("pul").value = point;interval();}
    function fermafatica() {time = timecache;setInterval(ferma, fatica);} //here the function equals time to timecache so vas time is always 1000ms//
    function ferma(){time = 10000; setTimeout(fermafatica, sudore);} // then here I transformed the time in 10000 so the first function will take 10000 instead of 1000 in setTimeout//
//plus i put a setTimeout to recall function fermafatica() that reset the time to 1000//
```

this i what i want... I avoid the problem and found another way to do that... but it works... thank you anyway